# What is the way to change the top right portion of SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, css

we are looking at branding our SharePoint 2013 site.

What is the way to clear out all the stuff on top right corner like NewsFeed, skydrive, share, follow?

Is it possible via designer/VS? I have changed the top left text via powershell.. Can the top right things can be cleared off using delegate controls or CSS or commenting off something in master page?

Ideally I would prefer something like a VS feature (module).

**UPDATE:**

Here is the answer with 3 possible solutions:- http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/09/sharepoint-2013-hide-newsfeed-skydrive-sites-deltasuitelinks/

*Option 1* - Remove or Hide the Delegate Control from Master Page. Open your Master page in SharePoint 2013 Designer and look for “SuiteLinksDelegate” delegate control.
In master page you would look for something like below -

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl id=”ID_SuiteLinksDelegate” ControlId=”SuiteLinksDelegate” runat=”server” />
```

Simply Remove or Comment it out.

*Option 2* - Using JavaScript to to hide the links Control.

```
<script language=”javascript”>
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(“HideBrandingsuite”);
function HideBrandingsuite()
{  
document.getElementById(‘ctl00_DeltaSuiteLinks’).style.visibility = ‘hidden’;
}
</script>
```

*Option 3* -  Creating a Visual Studio Solution for Overriding SuiteLinksDelegate Delegate Control.

Comment: You can get a start here: http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages (SuiteLinksDelegate)

Comment: Hi Robert, what about using security trimming to achieve this? is it possible?

Comment: Security trimming would be up to your delegate to handle (you sure as h*ll can not do it in the js,CSS approach so you would have to use the code behind of your delegate)

Comment: I did not get your point can you explain please

Comment: The point being that you would need to write security trimming logic in the delegate control

Comment: I mean that we can enclose the div (top right box) in a SharePoint:SecurityTrimmedControl and decide who can see it. Thats what I am referring to....

Comment: Of course you can, why shouldn't you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [Zimmergren's blogpost regarding new delegate controls in SP 2013](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages):

Create a module with the following in the Elements file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <!-- DelegateControl reference to the SuiteLinksDelegate Delegate Control -->
  <Control ControlSrc="/_controltemplates/15/Zimmergren.DelegateControls/SuiteLinksDelegate.ascx"
           Id="SuiteLinksDelegate"
           Sequence="1" />

</Elements>
```

(Of course replace controlsrc to point to an ASCX in your solution.) You will have to play a bit with the Sequence ID to make sure your control overwrites the existing one (increase or decrease the number)

In the code behind of that ASCX you can put the following:

```
public partial class SuiteLinksDelegate : MySuiteLinksUserControl
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer); // Should render nothing
    }
}
```

**Edit, for basic CSS**

You can also hide it with CSS, by using the following selector

```
#suiteLinksBox {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, can you post the CSS method, if possible, as well. (something that can be done via designer and css or setting visible to false...)

Comment: Appended my answer with a css selector for the lazy ;)

Comment: what about updating masterpage with following. This can be done via SPDesigner as well as VS2013 module project. What is your view on this?:- <SharePoint:SPSharePromotedActionButton runat="server" Visible="false"/>
     <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PromotedActions" AllowMultipleControls="true" Visible="false"/>
     <SharePoint:SPSyncPromotedActionButton runat="server" Visible="false"/>
     <SharePoint:PageStateActionButton id="PageStateActionButton" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<span id="fullscreenmodebox" class="ms-qatbutton" style="visibility:hidden">

Comment: The promoted actions is another delegate control, not the same

Comment: I have used the foll. code:- <SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" id="DeltaSuiteLinks" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-core-deltaSuiteLinks" Visible="false">    This method can be used via editing the masterpage as well as by creting module project in VS2013. What is your view on this?

Comment: What you do here is hiding the whole Delta delegate control containing the elements, I see not problem with this approach. The downside I can think about is that if you need to modify instead of hide, this method gives you no flexibility :)

Comment: what about using security trimming to achieve this? is it possible?